# KafkaMagic tool to search for messages in topic with field that is not null

Tags: apache-kafka

Need to find messages in kafka topic using KafkaMagic that have an exising attribute, i.e. not null. But javascript query falls with error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rpo_info') at (Script:3:57)
```

My filter query:

```
return (Context.Message.content.operation_info.rpo_info.rpo_info.source_bar_code != null);
```

I presume if source_bar_code does not exists in a message it cannot check if it is null.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Incorrect messages in topic. There were messages with keys before source_bar_code (rpo_info) were null.